# Git: vicious circle while squashing... commit disappears from log after rebasing

Tags: git

I have several commits to squash (but not all of them needs to be squashed!):

```
commit b1
commit b2
commit c1
commit c2
commit d1
commit m2
```

I type `git rebase -i HEAD~6`:

```
commit b1
s b2
s c1
s c2
s m2
```

And finally, I got desired commit with all squashed commits!

But when I'm trying to push these changes into my dev branch (myBranch)
, I got the following well-known error:

```
    ! [rejected]            myBranch -> myBranch (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@....git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

As it requires, I'm typing `git pull --rebase origin myBranch` and then my commit got disappeared from `git log` and everything is back again!

How to fix this and push squashed commits into the dev branch? What step is wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Not all of them needs to be squashed, you realize that removing them from the rebase instructions also removes the commits? In particular, commit `d1` will be removed as part of your rebase.

Comment: Also, are you squashing/rebasing commits that have already been pushed? If you do then `git push` will complain because you've essentially rewritten history and need to do a "force push" but please make sure you understand the consequences.

Comment: The reason why git pull rebase seems to remove your squash commit is that as part of the "replaying" your work on top of the new branch, merges/commits that ends up being empty (not introducing any changes) will be removed. Since your squash commit essentially adds the exact same changes that the branch already contains it is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine. That message from git is misleading. Instead you need to add `-f` to the push command.

The reason is that git tries to protect you from accidentally losing history due to replacing the remote branch head (instead of a fast forward push). So you need too force the push. If you are working with other people, you will need to communicate with them beforehand, but I will assume you are working alone here.